# C# ef map entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 entities:

```
  public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Companies = new Company();
        this.Language = new Language();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Companies { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public string LanguageId { get; set; } 
 }

  public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Categories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}


     public class Language
{
    public Language()
    {
        this.Categories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and then i have my mapings on category:

```
    public class CategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        //Primary Key
        this.HasKey(w => new { w.Id, w.LanguageId, w.Company} );

        //Properties
        this.Property(w => w.Id)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(w => w.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(w => w.ParentId)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(w => w.Sequence)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(w => w.Company)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(w => w.CompanyId)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(w => w.LanguageId)
            .IsRequired();

        //Table and columns mappings
        this.ToTable("Category");
        this.Property(w => w.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        this.Property(w => w.Name).HasColumnName("name");
        this.Property(w => w.ParentId).HasColumnName("parentid");
        this.Property(w => w.Sequence).HasColumnName("Sequence");
        this.Property(w => w.CompanyId).HasColumnName("CompanyId");
        this.Property(w => w.Company).HasColumnName("Company");
        this.Property(w => w.LanguageId).HasColumnName("languageid");

        //Relastionships
        this.HasRequired(w => w.Companies)
            .WithMany(y => y.Categories)
            .HasForeignKey(w => w.CompanyId);
        this.HasRequired(w => w.Language)
            .WithMany(w => w.Categories)
            .HasForeignKey(w => w.LanguageId);
    }
   }
```

then in my repository i do this:

```
  var translatedCategory = ctx.Category.Include(w => w.Companies).Include(w => w.Language).First(w => w.Id == category.Id);
```

and i want it to find companies and language but they are always a new object.

[image]

so what is wrong? why doesn't it find the company connected to that entity?

Comment: Should this line be this.HasKey(w => new { w.Id, w.LanguageId, w.Company} );  CompanyId ?

Comment: yeah becuase i use an very old database where the key is an composite key where it doesn't use the company id but the companyname instead which in that entity is called just company.

Comment: i added the companyid to that table so that it could reference it from company as a foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: You've set relationships up between them. You don't need to use .Include.

```
var translatedCategory = ctx.Category.Where(x => x.Companies.Id == someID);
```

Comment: ok but it doesn't help me. I added include because they where null

Comment: @Daniel Gustafsson I was just adding a suggestion. As for the question, I would look at the way your relationships are set up in CategoryMap. They didn't make it very intuitive on how to set this up properly but from the looks of it you are setting up a many to many relationship that will have a category that has a company with many categories.